# Extract Individual particular element from Nested item in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am new to MongoDB. 
I have created a collection in MongoDB and stored the following

```javascript
Q1UsefulStatementsList: [{
    Q1UsefulStatement: "Useful Sentence"
    Q1ActionsList: [{
        Q1Verb: "Verb in the sentence"
        Q1NP: "The Noun phrase"
        Q1PP: "The Preposition phrase"
    }]
}]
Q2UsefulStatementsList: [{
    Q2UsefulStatement: "Useful Sentence"
    Q2ActionsList: [{
        Q2Verb: "Verb in the Sentence"
        Q2NP: "The Noun phrase"
        Q2PP: "The preposition Phrase"
    }]
}]
```

I need to loop through this collection and get all the Verbs from Q1UsefulStatementsList and Q2UsefulStatementsList.
Ex:

```javascript
Q1UsefulStatementsList: [{
    Q1UsefulStatement: "My dog also likes eating sausage"
    Q1ActionsList: [{
        Q1Verb: "likes"
        Q1NP: "My dog"
        Q1PP: "n / a"
    }]
} {
    Q1UsefulStatement: "The disabling of log helps"
    Q1ActionsList: [{
        Q1Verb: "disabling"
        Q1NP: "disaabling of logs"
        Q1PP: "of"
    }]
}]
Q2UsefulStatementsList: [{
    Q2UsefulStatement: "Log analysis failed"
    Q2ActionsList: [{
        Q2Verb: "failed"
        Q2NP: "Log analysis"
        Q2PP: "n / a"
    }]
}]
```

I would like to get 'likes' and 'disabling' as output when I run through Q1UsefulStatementsList.

I have tried it using the code below. But is there a easier way to do these sort of things in MongoDB?

I tried using the 'dot operator' like (Q1UsefulStatementsList.Q1UsefulStatement) but what it gives me is a entire BSON(JSON) object. What I need is actual individual values directly.

Do suggest any easier way if any.

The Java code that I have written to extract the values

```java
if (object.get("Q1UsefulStatementsList") != null) {
    BasicDBList qUseStatementList = (BasicDBList)(object.get("Q1UsefulStatementsList"));

    for (Object qUsefulStatement: qUseStatementList) {
        DBObject tmp = (DBObject) qUsefulStatement;

        if (tmp.get("Q1ActionsList") != null) {
            BasicDBList qActionsList = (BasicDBList) tmp.get("Q1ActionsList");
            for (Object qVerbs: qActionsList) {
                DBObject tmpQVerbs = (DBObject) qVerbs;
                String verb = (tmpQVerbs.get("Q1Verb").toString());
                String nP = (tmpQVerbs.get("Q1NP").toString());
                String pP = (tmpQVerbs.get("Q1PP").toString());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/), specifically the [$unwind pipeline operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aggregation Framework to get the verbs you want. You can do it with the following code.

```
db.myObject.aggregate(
{ $unwind : "$Q1UsefulStatementsList"},
{ $unwind : "$Q1UsefulStatementsList.Q1ActionsList"},
{$group:{ _id: "$_id", verbs : {$addToSet : "$Q1UsefulStatementsList.Q1ActionsList.Q1Verb"}}}
);
```

This will return results as follow :

```
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5253e46ae3a2c44e082642c9"),
        "verbs" : ["disabling", "likes"]
    }
]
```

By looping the result array you can extract verbs array and add it to the Set in order to get unique verbs.

You can easily convert it to Java code.